# Why Edit Controls inside a Parent Window with WS_CHILD are disabled?

Tags: c, winapi, controls

I have created a window with `WS_CHILD` specified inside CreateWindowEx function, as follows:

```
HWND newEvent = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CONTROLPARENT, NewEventClassName, NewEventTitle, 
                               WS_BORDER | WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_CHILD, 
                               CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 
                               400, 230, hwnd, NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

Then, I created an Edit Control inside it:

```
HWND editCtrlEventName;
editCtrlEventName = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, L"EDIT", L"EVENT_NAME", 
                                   WS_GROUP | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE |
                                   ES_LEFT | ES_UPPERCASE, 110, 10, 130, 20,
                                   newEvent, (HMENU)2001, NULL, NULL);
```

When the window is created, the edit control is created, but disabled inside it and I can't enable the control by any means. I already tried to use `EnableWindow()` function and similars in my Edit Control, but with no success. However, when I delete `WS_CHILD` style from `newEvent`, it works perfectly.

I'm a beginner at winapi programming and this behavior is not clear for me. Is there any problem in creating edit controls inside child windows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> HWND newEvent = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CONTROLPARENT, NewEventClassName, NewEventTitle, 
>                                WS_BORDER | WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_CHILD, 
>                                CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 
>                                400, 230, hwnd, NULL, NULL, NULL);
> ```

The mistake in the above code is to combine two styles which are mutually exclusive: `WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_CHILD`.
`WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW` is a style only for top-level windows, and `WS_CHILD` of course only for child windows.

Also, `CW_USEDEFAULT` is not valid for a child window.

Other than that, there shouldn't be any problems creating an edit control as the child window of another child window. Windows itself uses this technique in many places, for instance a combobox has an edit control as child window.